# Set JMenu Direction RTL

Tags: java, swing, right-to-left, jmenu

I have a `jMenuBar1` and there are two `jMenu` items (say `jMenu1` and `jMenu2`) added to the `jMenuBar1`.

I managed to align the `jMenuBar1` object with this line of code :

```
jMenuBar1.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
```

Now I am trying to align the text in jMenu Items to right and making the text RTL(Right to Left) but nothing seems to work.
I have already tried

```
Menu1.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
jMenu1.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.RIGHT);
```

and no luck.

any solution will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in the parts you posted. Can you post more relevant code?

Comment: what are you trying to align to what else and why do you add the glue?

Comment: `jMenu1.applyComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);`

Comment: @kleopatra the name of the menu , like 'create member' i want to align the text to right

Comment: @MarounMaroun the text is aligned to left . this is the order : there is an icon in the left then there is the text in the middle and then there is the shortcut keys.

Comment: @JavaDevil nope, that does not work

Comment: should work - show an SSCCE that demonstrates the problem

Answer (score 1):

You might need to give us more information maybe some screen shots of what you have and what you are trying to achieve as `menu.setComponentOrientation()` seems to work fine for me...

I get this

[image]

running this

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MenuTest extends JFrame{

    public static void display()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(400,400);
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(6,1));
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        menuBar.applyComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        JMenu jMenu1 = new JMenu("Menu1");
        jMenu1.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200, 20));
        jMenu1.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(200, 20));
        jMenu1.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        JMenu jMenu2 = new JMenu("Menu2");
        jMenu2.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200, 20));
        jMenu2.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(200, 20));
        JMenuItem menuItem1 = new JMenuItem("Item1");
        JMenuItem menuItem2 = new JMenuItem("Item2");
        menuItem1.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200, 20));
        menuItem1.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(200, 20));
        menuItem1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 20));
        menuItem1.setSize(new Dimension(200, 20));
        menuItem2.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200, 20));
        menuItem2.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(200, 20));
        menuItem1.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        menuItem2.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        jMenu1.setHorizontalAlignment(JMenu.TRAILING);
        jMenu1.add(menuItem1);
        jMenu1.add(menuItem2);
        menuBar.add(jMenu1);
        menuBar.add(jMenu2);
        menuBar.setSize(frame.getWidth(), 20);
        frame.add(menuBar);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(
                new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        MenuTest.display();
                    }
                }
         );
    }
}
```

Comment: unrelated to the question: don't [tweak the sizing hints](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/203657) (aka: setXXSize) and don't do any manual sizing (aka: setSize)

Comment: related: guessing (no IDE handy to confirm) that you need not call setCO on each child if you first add them and then call applyCO on the toplevel parent

Comment: @kleopatra Re: sizing, Thanks for the hint, was more to point out the setCO working. Re: calling after added children, that was my thought also but when I tried that it didn't seem to propagate to children.

Comment: thanks for the info (and doing my work in checking my guess :-)

Comment: hmm ... actually, applyComponentOrientation worksforme in your example: first build the menubar without any tweaking of the menu/items, then call applyCO on the menubar and the menubar and the complete component hierarchy below appear in RToL as it should. BTW: a menubar has its own method frame.setJMenuBar

Comment: OK thanks, I didnt actually try applyCO..Even after suggesting it. Anyway hope this has all been somewhat of a help to the OP